# How can I implement socketIO in C# to work with NodeJS?

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I've been trying to implement the **Emit** **Broadcast** and **On** methods on C#.

**I KNOW** there is a package called SocketIO4DotNet and I do not wish to use it as it is deprecated. I rather understand how to do it.

I have tried to read the code of that package but it uses too dependancies over dependencies and it is going nowhere.

Currently I have the following code:

```
public class SocketIO
    {
        protected string host;

        protected int port;

        TcpClient client;

        public SocketIO(string host, int port)
        {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
        }

        public bool connect()
        {
            if (isConnected())
            {
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient();
                client.Connect(host, port);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                client = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool close()
        {
            if (!isConnected())
            {
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                client = null;

            }
            return true;
        }

        public void Emit(string message, string data)
        {
            if (!isConnected())
            {
                return;
            }

            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);

        }

        protected bool isConnected()
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I need to understand how to create the listener (On method) and how to use the Emit and Broadcast in a way that I send a message along with the data.

Comment: You're asking way too much here.

Comment: @MarkC. Any suggestions on what can I do to me more precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since I am unity but I do not want to use SocketIO as MonoBehaviour, I tweaked the Unity SocketIO package for unity to work without the Unity itself.

This is what I did:

First I have downloaded the package itself:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721

Then I changed the **SocketIOComponent** `Awake` method to be its constructor and changed its signature to accept the url (more params can be sent)

```
public SocketIOComponent(string url)
```

The next thing I did was creating a wrapper which I have called **SocketIOAdapter**

This is the code:

```
public class SocketIOAdapter {

    SocketIOComponent socketIO;
    protected Thread socketThread;
    public SocketIOAdapter(string url)
    {
        socketIO = new SocketIOComponent(url);
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        socketIO.Connect();
        socketThread = new Thread(socketIO.Update);
        socketThread.Start();
    }

    public void Emit(string eventName, JSONObject json)
    {
        socketIO.Emit(eventName, json);
    }

    public void On(string eventName, System.Action<SocketIOEvent> callback)
    {
        socketIO.On(eventName, callback);
    }
}
```

And lastly I have tweaked the Update method of **SocketIOComponent** to sleep and continue rather than return, like this:

```
if (ackList.Count == 0)
{
   Thread.Sleep(100);
   continue;
}
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(ackList[0].time).TotalSeconds < ackExpirationTime)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    continue;
}
```

Finally I have used it like this:

```
socketIO = new SocketIOAdapter(serviceManager.getConfig().get("servers.socket") as string);
socketIO.Connect();
socketIO.On("connect", this.OnConnect);
```

Listened like this:

```
void OnConnect(SocketIOEvent e)
{
    socketIO.Emit("shoot", new JSONObject("{}"));
}
```

So far so good, it's working well. 
Hope this helps someone out there.